# ContextManuStripTool.show() position is wrong

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, mouseevent, contextmenustrip

I'm trying to learn how to use the `ContextMenuStrip`

when using this code :

```
private void DG_dataGridView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var hitTest = DG_dataGridView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

            if (hitTest.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader)//currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
            {
                string colName = DG_dataGridView.Columns[hitTest.ColumnIndex].Name;
                GlobalParam.Insatance.ClickData = new RightClickData(hitTest, colName);

                RightClickToolStrip.Show(DG_dataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));
            }
        }
}
```

I see the menu pop up in the right position

but when instead I use this code :

```
    private void DG_dataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {

            var hitTest = DG_dataGridView.HitTest(e.Location.X, e.Location.Y);

            string colName = DG_dataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name;
            GlobalParam.Insatance.CustomMouseGridClickData = new CustomMouseOnGridClickData(e, hitTest.Type, colName);


            RightClickToolStrip.Show(DG_dataGridView, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        }

    }
```

I see the menu pop on the top left corner of my `DataGridView`

I know this is due to the operation of `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs`
I have tried to set other control in the `toolStrip.Show` method without success 
what is the proper way to get my click position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the ColumnHeaderMouseClick event, you don't have to test for the column getting clicked or not using that HitTest method.  Also, I think the coordinates are relative to the column being clicked, so you can try using the GetColumnDisplayRectangle function to offset it property:

```
void DG_dataGridView_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) {
    if (e.ColumnIndex > -1) {
      Rectangle r = DG_dataGridView.GetColumnDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, true);
      RightClickToolStrip.Show(DG_dataGridView, r.Left + e.X, r.Top + e.Y);
    }
  }
}
```